# Node.js for server to server communication

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am wondering if node.js is good for use in a server side application which is not actually communicating with the browser, or browser communication is just an additional part of whole app used rather for management.

The idea is simple:

1. Server receives high amount of UDP traffic with short messages containing user data from another server.
2. For each message app performs DB lookup and filter out messages with userid's that are not on the whitelist.
3. Filtered messages are processed, which result in another DB update, or sending data to another server.

Is such case, a good scenario to learn node.js, or maybe there is no benefit from it comparing to e.g Java EE?

Comment: I think this is an excellent pet program to write ( depending on the database ) , check http://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html for documentation

Comment: Node works best if most of your time is spent in IO (db, disk, network, etc). While your app is performing IO, node is free to handle more requests. If it's doing a lot of CPU intensive processing, then it's stuck doing that and nothing else. Most of what you listed sounds perfect for node, except maybe "Filtered messages are processed". If that processing is expensive, then you may have an issue.

Comment: Did you hit a problem with java EE ? performances or concurrency ? you have a lot of solutions for concurrency within java , is it worth to add another layer with a different language , i dont think so , unless what you've tried failed.

Comment: I am JS developer not Java developer. I have two possibilities: 1. Delegate this task to Java developer (drawback: would take a lot of time in my organization, to schedule this), 2. Do it by myself and threat this as an chance to learn sth new. That is why I am asking for JEE comparision. If this scenario is completely missing the node.js point I would go for 1st solution. If JEE and node.js could be comperable in performance I would probably go for 2nd solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I work for a company that contributes to node.js and promotes its usage, so my opinion might be biased.*

As others mentioned in comments, node.js should be a good fit for you scenario. It is actually one of the most common scenarios where people use node.js - fetch data from (possibly multiple) sources, do a small amount of CPU-light processing and send back the response or store the result. Unless message filtering is very CPU expensive, node.js implementation will probably outperform J2EE version.

The reason is that Node.js is heavily optimised for solutions where the server spends most of the time waiting. Waiting for client connection, waiting for database response, waiting for disc read/write, waiting for client to read the response, etc.

J2EE is employing multi-threading, where you have one thread to handle each request, which is suboptimal in this case. Most threads are waiting, so you are not getting the benefit of running lots of code in parallel, but you still have to pay the price of context switching and higher memory usage.

There is one thing I would consider before going for node.js: are you able and allowed to deploy node.js into your production environment?  Moving to a new platform has some associated costs, people operating your application will have to learn how to deal with node.js applications.

Comment: >`node.js implementation will probably outperform Java EE version` - Do you have data to support this? This benchmark for instance doesn't exactly support your assertion: http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r5

Comment: >`Java EE is employing multi-threading, where you have one thread to handle each request` - This is one option. Java EE supports asynchronous HTTP processing just as well. See e.g. http://www.javakeexample.com/2013/01/creating-asynchronous-servlets-with.html and https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/asynchronous_support_in_servlet_3

Comment: @ArjanTijms Good points. I don't have hard data to support my claim about performance. However the benchmark you are referring to is flawed, they use mysql client that has known performance problems. Regarding async J2EE - async servlet is probably not enough, you should use async for communicating to DB, etc. and that's not the usual usage for J2EE components, is it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The benchmark guys are open for community contribution, but changing the DB may be hard (ASP.NET e.g. wanted SQL Server instead). As for Java EE (not J2EE ;)), async DB communication to a DB can be done via the `@Asynchronous` annotation that you apply to a method. I think it's typical to use this, at least I've personally used it a lot.